# ШирокоПОЛОСНИЙ чи широкоСМУГОВИЙ доступ до інтернету?

Tags: вибір-слова, прикметники

На просторах Інтернету натрапила на 2 слова, що позначають доступ до мережі, з високою швидкістю передачі даних за кількома каналами одночасно - [**широкоПОЛОСНИЙ**](https://www.unian.ua/science/10070093-poroshenko-shirokopolosniy-internet-maye-z-yavitis-u-kozhnomu-seli.html) і [**широкоСМУГОВИЙ**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF_%D0%B4%D0%BE_%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83). Цікаво, що стаття у [Вікіпедії](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF_%D0%B2_%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82) російською мовою використовує слово **широкоПОЛОСНИЙ**.

В [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/polosa) в словниковій статті біля слова **полоса** немає ніяких позначок, які б обмежували його вживання (*чи причина в тому, що це слово вживається лише при означенні газет і журналів?*). Однак, у [Блозі проф. Пономарева](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2016/04/160411_ponomariv_blog85_ko) знаходжу:

> Як українською мовою перестроиться в соседнюю полосу?
>
> Перешикуватися в сусідню смугу.

Отже, як нормативно вживати: **широкоСМУГОВИЙ** чи **широкоПОЛОСНИЙ** ?

Answer (score 1):

Ви самі відповіли на своє запитання. [*Полоса*](http://sum.in.ua/s/polosa) в українській мові використовується лише у одному значенні, що не стосується доступу до Інтернету. В українській мові російська "полоса" - це "смуга", а отже правильно казати *"широкосмуговий"*, а *"широкополосний"* -  калька з російської.